# State of Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, http2, koa

I'm migrating an app to Node 12. It still uses the npm module "spdy" to make HTTP/2 available to Express.

Unfortunately, "spdy" doesn't run on Node 12:

- [spdy issue](https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy/issues/350)
- [handle-thing issue](https://github.com/spdy-http2/handle-thing/issues/6)

So I decided to give Node.js's HTTP/2 module a chance (reducing the amount of dependencies is mostly good) and found that [Express doesn't work with Node.js's HTTP/2 module](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+http2).

After inspecting the activity on Express I'm wondering how I could miss that it's abandoned. Does anyone know *if* it's abandoned and why and in favor of which framework (I assume [koa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa))?

Comment: From "Awesome Node.js" I see that koa is built by the Express team. Seems koa is the way to go…
https://nodejs.libhunt.com/express-alternatives

Comment: Seems koa is also abandoned...